# Como hacer un texto no seleccionable

Tags: html

Quisiera saber cómo puedo hacer que un texto no se pueda seleccionar. LO máximo que puedo hacer es que el cursor no cambie haciendo esto:

```css
.p {
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<p class="p">Texto de ejemplo</p>
```

Alguien em puede ayudar por favor

Comment: Muy simple, usa [`user-select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) con un valor de `none` y ya con eso queda

Comment: muchas gracias amigo

Comment: Considera que además del enlace que te dejé debes además observar que funciona bien pero debes agregarle prefijos para el soporte: https://caniuse.com/?search=user-select

Answer (score 1):

```
.p {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select:none;
    user-select:none;
}
```

Comment: Te invito a que leas [answer]

Comment: Además ¿este prefijo `-khtml` a qué navegador corresponde?

Comment: si tienes razón

Comment: El prefijo `-ms` es para **Internet Explorer**, un "navegador" (entre infinitas comillas) que casi nadie usa, en estos tiempos no creo que se ponga tanto